# what is the main difference between linear discriminant analysis and pronciple component analysis

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matching, emgucv, feature-extraction

"The Principal Component Analysis (PCA), which is the core of the Eigenfaces method, finds a linear combination of features that maximizes the total variance in data. While this is clearly a powerful way to represent data, it doesn’t consider any classes and so a lot of discriminative information may be lost when throwing components away." (Open CV)

What is mean by "CLASSES" here????

"
Linear Discriminant Analysis maximizes the ratio of between-classes to within-classes scatter, instead of maximizing the overall scatter. The idea is simple: same classes should cluster tightly together, while different classes are as far away as possible from each other in the lower-dimensional representation.

in here also what is mean by CLASSES????

Can some one please explain this in image processing view thanx

Answer (score 2):

Classes in these contexts means groups or classifications. Like 'faces' or 'letters', things that have a set of geometric properties that can be identified with some degree of generality. PCA tried to classify objects in an image by them selves while LDS tries to classify things with some consideration to how many of the same thing they are near.

An example might be a picture of the ball "Wilson". By itself a it doesn't look much like a face and PCA would give it a low likelihood as being a face, but an LDS approach if the picture included Tom Hanks right next to it would classify Tom Hanks as having a face and cause the Wilson to more likely be a face as well. As you can see from this contrived example depending on what you are trying to achieve (and how good your data is) each approach has its upsides and downsides.

Comment: im going to match the sketch face (drawing photo) in to the color photo. so for the research i want to find out what are the challenges that matching sketch drawing in to color faces. for now i have find out that

1. resolution pixel difference 2. texture difference 3. distance difference 4. and color (not much effect)

i wanna know that in technical terms what are other challenges and im going to use Fisher face method under linear discriminant analysis   and can you please tell me will that method help for me to do this. thanx

Comment: You are working on a much harder problem than I can help with but this comment could almost stand as its own question and there are some smart people here that I'm sure could help. If possible include a test picture. Good luck!

Comment: Never mind, I can see that you already tried that. One sec, I'll add a bounty to it to see if you have more luck (and add some example pictures, it will address a valid comment made on your first question)

Comment: thnx very much               the photos from CUHK database (https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdjASOuJxbomtzt09qM9ko7gapf1s6Tf9kFpEob325DNkfG5DI)   all the photos are front facing same background and i want to address one of challenge that when matching sketch in to photo and build the system

Comment: It looks like I have to wait one more day before the question can have a bounty, until then I've added the image you liked to to your original question.  Because a question receives most of it's exposure the first few hours that it's posted you might think about deleting the other question and re-posting a more concise question (with a clear example as well as any work you have done so far).

Answer (score 2):

TO make it simple, PCA tries to represent the total data in minimum dimension. LDA also tries to do the same but also make sure that the different classes can be differentiated(classification). PCA does not help in classification. It helps only in dimesionality reduction. SO LDA = PCA + classification